# Displacement Equation Question

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

In the displacement equation:

`d = vt + 1/2(a)(t)^2`

What does the 1/2 signify?

If I alter the equation to `1/2*t(v + (a)(t))`. This I can interpret as ∆time multiplied by average velocity – although it's probably not the right interpretation.

But why isn't 1/2 being applied to both variables? What am I missing?

Comment: Would be nice to know why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing calculus. :)

I'll re-write your displacement equation for linear motion under constant acceleration $a$ like this:

$$x = ut + a t^2/2$$

where $x$ is displacement and $u$ is initial velocity, because I want to use $v$ for instantaneous velocity.

From your question, it appears that you understand that the mean velocity over an interval of time $\Delta t$ is given by

$$v_{mean} = \Delta x / \Delta t$$

where $\Delta x$ is the change in displacement that occurs during $\Delta t$.

We can use that formula to determine the *instantaneous* velocity by finding the *limit* that $\Delta x / \Delta t$ approaches as $\Delta t$ approaches zero. When you study calculus, this notion of limits, and the technique I use below, will be made rigorous, but at this stage you should be able to get the general idea, even if it does seem a little bit dubious. :)

Starting with our displacement equation, we want to calculate the change in $x$ when we make a small change in $t$.

$$\begin{align}
x & = ut + a t^2/2\\
x + \Delta x & = u(t + \Delta t) + a (t + \Delta t)^2/2\\
\Delta x & = u(t + \Delta t) + a (t^2 + 2t \Delta t + \Delta t^2)/2 - (ut +  a t^2/2)\\
& = u \Delta t + a (2t \Delta t + \Delta t^2)/2\\
& = u \Delta t + a (t \Delta t + \Delta t^2 /2)\\
\Delta x/\Delta t & = u + at + \Delta t / 2\\
\end{align}$$
As $\Delta t$ approaches zero that final $\Delta t / 2$ term vanishes, $\Delta x/\Delta t$ approaches $v$, and thus we get

$$v = u + at$$

the well-known velocity equation for linear motion under constant acceleration.